# how does the symfony v6 cli locate the platform (platform.sh) executable?

Tags: php, windows, symfony, symfony-cli

I am trying out the integration between the Symfony 6 cli and platform.sh.  All commands in the symfony cli "cloud" namespace fail because the symfony cli is looking for the platform executable in the wrong place.  The error message comes back

```
exec: "C:\\cygwin64\\home\\dougw\\.platformsh\\bin\\platform": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Oddly, cygwin64 is not installed on my machine (anymore) and the platform executable was installed via scoop.  Also, the platform executable is available in powershell.  The scoop "shims" are in place and working correctly.

I could tell the symfony cli where to find the platform executable if that were absolutely necessary, if only I knew how.  But that seems like working around scoop.

Why is the symfony cli not just looking for platform.exe in the path first (e.g. ~\scoop\shims).  I have no idea how the symfony cli decided to look in c:\cygwin64\etc..... I have uninstalled and reinstalled the symfony cli, but it made no difference.

Comment: Run the code in a debugger?

Comment: Appreciate the thought.  the symfony cli is an executable and is compiled, not interpreted.  how would I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli is the code perhaps, though only you know what you really installed. That code is written in Go, so you should be able to debug it after getting the required tools. Anyhow, you could look at the sourcecode, search e.g. for "platform". That said, I'm not sure what happened and with the little info provided, can't tell.

Comment: helpful thanks.  Looked through the code and found the relevant piece.  Have a little configuration work to do to see if I can fix my environment.

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony CLI relies on the $HOME environment variable.  In my case, it was set to something non-sensical, which I fixed.  BUT, the symfony cli is hardcoded to look in $HOME/.platformsh/bin for the platform executable.  So you need to put a copy of the executable there in order for the symfony cli to find it.  It is worth noting perhaps that the direction to install the platform cli on windows instructs one to use scoop. Scoop is a nice utility, but it will NOT put the executable in the directory mentioned above.  You will need to copy it manually.  Just copy the single file platform.exe to the correct directory, that is all that is required.